# the code does not work with any browser like chrome,firefox and edge

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

i am trying to make the following piece of code display the current date and time in the browser,after saving the file "date-time.js" using "utf-8" encoding

tried running on different browsers like firefox,chrome and edge ,

```
// tell the browser to run this script when the page has finished loading
window.onload = insertDateTime;

// insert the date and time 
function insertDateTime() {
    // to ensure a DOM aware user-agent(i.e. browser) 
    if (!document.getElementById) return;
    if (!document.createTextNode) return;

    // create a Date-Time object
    var oNow = new Date();

    // get the current date and time as a string
    var sDateTime = oNow.toLocaleString();

    // point to the target element where the date-time is to be inserted
    var oTarget = document.getElementById(' output ');

    // make sure the target is found
    if (!oTarget) return;

    // delete everything inside the target element
    while (oTarget.firstChild) {
        oTarget.removeChild(oTarget.firstChild);
    }

    // use the new date-time to create a new text node for the page
    var oNewText = document.createTextNode(sDateTime);

    // insert the new text into the span
    oTarget.appendChild(oNewText);
}
```

when the page is run in a browser it does not display the current date and time.

Comment: Try providing a [mcve], include the minimal HTML for it to work, format the code so it is readable, use the live demo feature in the question editor so people can just run it.

Comment: So your id has whitespace? `' output '`. Use your developer console I am betting it has errors listed.

Comment: "*`if (!document.getElementById) return;`*" - WTH, where did you find this code? Must be ancient.

Comment: "*when the page is run in a browser*" - which page exactly are you running, and how?

Comment: If I create an empty HTML page and put a div inside it with the id ` output `, including the spaces, everything works for me. So show your HTML. Probably going to be a typo or something, unless you are like trying to run  the .js file directly in the browser without placing it inside a HTML page.

Comment: i am sorry for not providing the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Firstly on the first line of code it needs to be like:

```
window.onload = insertDateTime();
```

you have forgotten adding parenthesis.

Secondly when you call the element by ID you have put spaces on the side of output like ' output ' which needs to be removed and be 'output'

It is just a type issue which I have fixed it below:

```
// tell the browser to run this script when the page has finished loading
window.onload = insertDateTime();

// insert the date and time 
function insertDateTime() {
    // to ensure a DOM aware user-agent(i.e. browser) 
    if (!document.getElementById) return;
    if (!document.createTextNode) return;

    // create a Date-Time object
    var oNow = new Date();

    // get the current date and time as a string
    var sDateTime = oNow.toLocaleString();

    // point to the target element where the date-time is to be inserted
    var oTarget = document.getElementById('output');

    // make sure the target is found
    if (!oTarget) return;

    // delete everything inside the target element
    while (oTarget.firstChild) {
        oTarget.removeChild(oTarget.firstChild);
    }

    // use the new date-time to create a new text node for the page
    var oNewText = document.createTextNode(sDateTime);

    // insert the new text into the span
    oTarget.appendChild(oNewText);
}
```

Comment: `window.onload = insertDateTime();` This line is incorrect. leaving the braces is correct, since you want to assign this function to window.onload. Adding the braces immediately runs the function and assigns undefined to window.onload. Which will make the script break if it's placed before the element with that id.